# Regex that accepts only numbers (0-9) and NO characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex that will accept only digits from 0-9 and nothing else. No letters, no characters.

I thought this would work:

```
^[0-9]
```

or even

```
\d+
```

but these are accepting the characters : ^,$,(,), etc

I thought that both the regexes above would do the trick and I'm not sure why its accepting those characters.

EDIT:

This is exactly what I am doing:

```
 private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

   if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("^[0-9]", textbox.Text))
        {
            textbox.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

This is allowing the characters I mentioned above.

Comment: Are you sure? `[0-9]` will only match 0-9...how did you test this?

Comment: These should work. You can verify by testing it [here](http://regextester.com/). It could be some other issue with your code.

Comment: \d+ works just fine of course if yo have "ab1-56$p" the IsMatch will return true because it matches the numbers in the string but `MatchCollection matches = new RegEx(@"(\d+)").Matches("ab1-56$p");` will give you 2 matches it's going to extract 1 and 56

Comment: Validators.pattern("^[0-9]{10}$")

Comment: @strings.refind("6767","^[0-9]*$")

Answer (score 744, accepted):

Your regex `^[0-9]` matches anything *beginning* with a digit, including strings like "1A". To avoid a partial match, append a `$` to the end:

```
^[0-9]*$
```

This accepts any number of digits, including none. To accept one or more digits, change the `*` to `+`. To accept exactly one digit, just remove the `*`.

**UPDATE:** You mixed up the arguments to `IsMatch`. The pattern should be the second argument, not the first:

```
if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textbox.Text, "^[0-9]*$"))
```

**CAUTION:** In JavaScript, `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`, but in .NET, `\d` by default matches any [Unicode decimal digit](http://graphemica.com/categories/decimal-digit-number), including exotic fare like ႒ (Myanmar 2) and ߉ (N'Ko 9). Unless your app is prepared to deal with these characters, stick with `[0-9]` (or supply the [RegexOptions.ECMAScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_10) flag).

Comment: This regex is allowing a string with only '$', please see my edit.

Comment: /^[0-9]*$/ as the correct answer.

Comment: In Javascript this is allowing the value 123-456 `(\d)*$`

Comment: @theB3RV: If you don't want to match hyphens, then you need to insert the `^` character at the beginning, as stated in the answer.

Comment: @xpioneer: ^ and $ are called *anchors*. ^ matches the beginning of the string, and $ matches the end of the string. By putting ^ at the beginning of your regex and $ at the end, you ensure that no other characters are allowed before or after your regex. For example, the regex `[0-9]` matches the strings "9" as well as "A9B", but the regex `^[0-9]$` only matches "9".

Comment: Just in case if someone want to allow negative(-) sign. /^-?[0-9]*$/

Comment: Personally I have had a lot of luck with the following: ([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?)

Comment: Validators.pattern("^[0-9]{10}$")

Comment: Even shorter: `^\d*$`

Comment: @strings.refind("6767","^[0-9]*$")