# Allow Numbers only in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, user-interface

I have a table named `CustomerAddr`. The table is for a user to enter customer's address information. One column named `StNumber` should only allow numeric characters ex. 0-9 just like a phone number, however the user entering the customers address information can put any characters; such as alpha, special characters etc.

I want the column `StNumber` to ONLY accept numeric values 0-9 four characters max. If  the user should try to enter anything but a number in the customers address information screen it should be blocked. I changed the data type for `StNumber` to `numeric(5)` but the user still can enter any character. 
Help would be great.

Comment: You need to make that validation on the UI at the time of user inputs values if it's is web application look at this http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/whats-new-in-html5-forms-handling-numeric-inputs-using-the-number-and-range-input-types.html#fbid=_HB79Wl8Ql_

Comment: `Numeric(5)` will never allow `character` something else wrong

Comment: As @Coder of Code says above, you should validate the data at the time of entry, not rely on the database to check it. The database should also use correct datatypes and constraints to "protect" itself and ensure that it only ever stores valid data. The best designed UIs don't allow the user to make mistakes, so would prevent entry of anything besides digits or dash. Either the field shouldn't accept the invalid keystroke, or the "Save" button should be disabled until all fields are valid. However you do it, the data shouldn't be sent to the database unless the program thinks it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE CustomerAddr
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_num CHECK (ISNUMERIC ( StNumber ))
```

Comment: I think OP is asking about UI validation `If the user should try to enter anything but a number in the customers address information screen it should be blocked`

Comment: @timus2001 - FYI `Isnumeric` has too many drawbacks. It will allow string like `'$1000', '1e1' `

Comment: @NoDisplayName - at least your examples contain *some* digits. I prefer the even less sane examples like `'£'` or `','`

Answer (score 0):

As all said, you are talking about UI validation. You should think about using regular expressions. For example, you can use the regular expression `^[0-9]*$` to make sure only numerals are typed. For your case, you can use `^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$` to accept only four digits.

Depending on the language you use, you need to know how to make this validation. For example, the below link gives an example in .NET:

[Regex that accepts only numbers (0-9) and NO characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715303/regex-that-accepts-only-numbers-0-9-and-no-characters)

Comment: Can I alter the table in a query to allow only numbers?

Comment: Sure, it depends on the DBMS you're using. For example: You can set the column data type to `smallint` in SQL Server and add a constraint to make sure it lies in a certain range to make sure no negative numbers are inserted.

Comment: Example for adding a constraint on column in SQL Server: `ALTER TABLE <Your Table> ADD CONSTRAINT <Contraint Name> CHECK (<Your Column> >= 0 AND <Your Column> <= 9999)`